# How to add css to a specific Array element on Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I'm trying to develope a code that generates a random RGB color for each element with the name "Title" on my website.

First, I choose **all** the elements with a specific class **"title"**:

```
var element = $('.title')
```

Then, I save on a **var** called ***n***, the total number of titles (used on the for)

```
var n = element.length
```

Now. I'm trying to traverse all the title elements and adding by css a random RGB color. Note: I use **element[ i ]**, to access each of the array element. Is that correct?

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    element[ i ].css({ 
        "background": randomColor();
    })
}
```

However it doesn't work... How can I solve that? Any idea.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

`element[i]` refers to the dom element which does not have the method [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) which is provided by jQuery, so you need to get the jQuery wrapper object for the element at index `i` which can be obtained by [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    element.eq(i).css({ 
        "background": randomColor();
    })
}
```

---

You can also pass a function to [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function) like

```
element.css('background', function () {
    return randomColor()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What you were doing is almost correct. Except for you didn't create a selector for the i-th element.

$(element[i]) will have the css() function available and would work as expected.